# ¿Cómo pasar datos de filas a columnas - SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas estoy mostrando un listado de personas con varios nombres de artefactos que compraron, al momento de mostrar el listado me salen nombres de personas repetidas pero con diferentes nombres de artefactos, lo que yo quisiera es hacer que ya no se muestren el listado de personas repetidas con artefactos diferentes, si no mostrar un listado de personas que tengan columnas con artefactos diferentes. He intentado hacer pero no me sale, aquí mi avance:

Código:

```
SELECT*
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 
    p.IdPersona, 
    p.ApellidoPaterno, 
    p.ApellidoMaterno, 
    p.Nombre, 
    p.DNI,
    p.FechaNacimiento,
    d.Descripcion as DNombreArtefacto
FROM Personas p
JOIN DArtefactos d ON p.IdDArtefactos = d.IdDArtefactos
)
AS SourceTable PIVOT
(
count(DNombreArtefacto) for DNombreArtefacto in ([DNombreArtefacto1],[DNombreArtefacto2])
) AS PivoteTable;
```

Con ese código solo me cargan ceros en las columnas de los nombres de artefactos pero no sus nombres.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir datos de muestra y los resultados que esperarías sobre los mismos? ¿Esperas que la cantidad de columnas para los nombres de artefactos varíe o siempre serán 2?

Comment: No conozco la función PIVOT, pero ¿no será que te arroja números porque estás llamando a 'count(DNombreArtefacto)...'? Intenta quitar el count y nos cuentas qué pasa...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aquí hay un ejemplo de como convertir los valores de filas en columnas. Existe una forma de hacerlo de forma dinámica, pero es importante que se entienda primero como hacerlo de forma estática para prevenir errores.

```
WITH ctePersonasArtefactos AS(
    SELECT 
        p.IdPersona      , 
        p.ApellidoPaterno, 
        p.ApellidoMaterno, 
        p.Nombre         , 
        p.DNI            ,
        p.FechaNacimiento,
        d.Descripcion    AS DNombreArtefacto,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY p.IdPersona ORDER BY d.Descripcion) AS NumArtefacto
    FROM Personas p
    JOIN DArtefactos d ON p.IdDArtefactos = d.IdDArtefactos
)
SELECT IdPersona      , 
       ApellidoPaterno, 
       ApellidoMaterno, 
       Nombre         , 
       DNI            ,
       FechaNacimiento,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumArtefacto = 1 THEN DNombreArtefacto END) AS DNombreArtefacto1,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumArtefacto = 2 THEN DNombreArtefacto END) AS DNombreArtefacto2,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumArtefacto = 3 THEN DNombreArtefacto END) AS DNombreArtefacto3,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumArtefacto = 4 THEN DNombreArtefacto END) AS DNombreArtefacto4,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumArtefacto = 5 THEN DNombreArtefacto END) AS DNombreArtefacto5,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumArtefacto = 6 THEN DNombreArtefacto END) AS DNombreArtefacto6
FROM ctePersonasArtefactos
GROUP BY IdPersona    , 
       ApellidoPaterno, 
       ApellidoMaterno, 
       Nombre         , 
       DNI            ,
       FechaNacimiento;
```

Existen varios puntosen esta consulta:

- Primero agregué la función [ROW_NUMBER()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) para poder controlar que todos los artefactos puedan ser identificados de una forma más controlable (siempre iniciando en 1 y sin saltos).
- Como ese valor no lo puedo referenciar en el resto de la consulta, lo incluyo en una [CTE (common table expression)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), la cual es como una subconsulta o "tabla derivada" que, en otras situaciones, puede tener más facultades.
- Al final, sólo utilicé una técnica disponible desde antes de que existiera la instrucción PIVOT para convertir filas en columnas. Esta técnica es la que prefiero porque es más versatil y llega a ser más eficiente. Esto lo aprendí de [este artículo en inglés](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/).

Comment: Gracias amigos, era justo lo que buscaba! Salio todo correctamente y ademas  agregaste algo mas ahi que me intereso. Una pregunta me podrias decir por favor que tema puedo estudiar para aprender a hacer todo esa consuta ya que soy nuevo en esto de sql server y aun no llego hasta eso?

Comment: Edite la respuesta para dar una mayor explicación a cada paso que realicé.

Comment: gracias amigo por responder, estare repasando entonces eso ya que veo que me puede ayudar para varios casos mas (y)

Answer (score 1):

Al hacer un `pivot` en SQL Server, debes indicar de antemano los nombres de las columnas que esperas obtener de la operación.

Lo que haría falta en tu consulta, básicamente, es que incluyas los nombres de los productos que esperas obtener en columnas.

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo con un *CTE* construido al vuelo, para que te hagas una mejor idea:

```
with
X as (
select 'Juan' NombreCliente, 'Ratón' Producto, 1 Cantidad
union all select 'Juan', 'Monitor', 1
union all select 'Pedro', 'PC', 1
)
select NombreCliente, [Ratón], [Monitor], [PC]
  from (select NombreCliente, Cantidad, Producto
          from X) as t1
        pivot (sum(Cantidad)
               for Producto in ([Ratón], [Monitor], [PC])
              ) as t2
```

El resultado que arroja esta consulta es, supongo, como el que esperas ver:

```
NombreCliente Ratón       Monitor     PC
------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Juan          1           1           NULL
Pedro         NULL        NULL        1

(2 rows affected)
```

Comment: lo que queria era en vez de poner cantidades, poner nombres. Aun asi gracias por el dato, me va a servir bastante! (y)