# Pasar datos de filas a columnas (dinamicas) - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy desarrollando una carga de datos parecido a un caso de una pregunta que se hizo hace unos días, solo que el mio varia un poco:

[¿Cómo pasar datos de filas a columnas - SQL Server?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/254644/c%C3%B3mo-pasar-datos-de-filas-a-columnas-sql-server#)

Aquí esta su código:

```
WITH ctePersonasArtefactos AS(
    SELECT 
        p.IdPersona      , 
        p.ApellidoPaterno, 
        p.ApellidoMaterno, 
        p.Nombre         , 
        p.DNI            ,
        p.FechaNacimiento,
        d.Descripcion    AS DNombreArtefacto,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY p.IdPersona ORDER BY d.Descripcion) AS NumArtefacto
    FROM Personas p
    JOIN DArtefactos d ON p.IdDArtefactos = d.IdDArtefactos
)
SELECT IdPersona      , 
       ApellidoPaterno, 
       ApellidoMaterno, 
       Nombre         , 
       DNI            ,
       FechaNacimiento,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumArtefacto = 1 THEN DNombreArtefacto END) AS DNombreArtefacto1,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumArtefacto = 2 THEN DNombreArtefacto END) AS DNombreArtefacto2,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumArtefacto = 3 THEN DNombreArtefacto END) AS DNombreArtefacto3,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumArtefacto = 4 THEN DNombreArtefacto END) AS DNombreArtefacto4,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumArtefacto = 5 THEN DNombreArtefacto END) AS DNombreArtefacto5,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumArtefacto = 6 THEN DNombreArtefacto END) AS DNombreArtefacto6
FROM ctePersonasArtefactos
GROUP BY IdPersona    , 
       ApellidoPaterno, 
       ApellidoMaterno, 
       Nombre         , 
       DNI            ,
       FechaNacimiento;
```

Lo que me gustaría hacer es pasar datos de la filas a columnas, pero según viendo el caso anterior solo son máximo 6 columnas o bueno eso es lo que entiendo. Pero si tengo mas datos? Serían mas columnas aun pasando los 6...hay alguna forma de hacer columnas dinámicas osea para obtener N filas y pasarlas a N columnas? Me podrían ayudar por favor. :s

PD: Vi que un usuario lo respondió pero no de forma dinámica, y no le pude preguntar a el por el motivo de que stack overflow me pide mas puntos para preguntar en otro lados...

Mi codigo:

```
WITH PacientesDiagnosticos AS(
    SELECT top 100
        p.IdPaciente      , 
       (p.ApellidoPaterno+' '+p.ApellidoMaterno+' '+p.PrimerNombre) as Nombres,
        p.NroDocumento         ,
        p.FechaNacimiento,
        d.Descripcion    AS Dignostico,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY p.IdPaciente ORDER BY d.Descripcion) AS NumArtefacto
    FROM Pacientes p
    JOIN Atenciones a ON p.IdPaciente = a.IdPaciente
    JOIN AtencionesDiagnosticos ad ON a.IdAtencion = ad.IdAtencion
    JOIN Diagnosticos d ON ad.IdDiagnostico = d.IdDiagnostico
)
SELECT IdPaciente      , 
       Nombres,
       NroDocumento           ,
       FechaNacimiento,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumArtefacto = 1 THEN Dignostico END) AS Dignostico1,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumArtefacto = 2 THEN Dignostico END) AS Dignostico2,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumArtefacto = 3 THEN Dignostico END) AS Dignostico3,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumArtefacto = 4 THEN Dignostico END) AS Dignostico4,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumArtefacto = 5 THEN Dignostico END) AS Dignostico5,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumArtefacto = 6 THEN Dignostico END) AS Dignostico6
FROM PacientesDiagnosticos
GROUP BY IdPaciente, 
       Nombres, 
       NroDocumento,
       FechaNacimiento;
```

Fue adaptado con el codigo anterior

Comment: El reporte que deseas sacar, va a ser una vista dentro del sql server o es solo un reporte con el cual podrías apoyarte en otras herramientas?! te pregunto esto porque de ser el segundo caso, podrías sacar un reporte con la data pura y luego usar por ejemplo excel para generar una tabla dinámica y entregar tu reporte.

Comment: @Rostan con el mismo sql server lo necesito amigo :s

Comment: de ser así lo que te recomiendo (ya que no tengo la experiencia) es que busques sobre pivotear tablas, por que al ser dinámica la cantidad de columnas a usar, no te sirve el ejemplo anterior.

Comment: @Rostan vere eso mientras entonces :s

Comment: Sí existe la forma de hacerlo dinámico. De hecho en esa solución hay un link a una serie de artículos que habla de como hacerlo. Sin embargo, sería bueno que compartieras algo un poco más apegado a tu situación o podríamos estar generando código innecesario.

Comment: @LuisCazares ! ah tu eres el del comentario, entonces subo un poco de mi codigo para que lo veas, te daras cuenta que es parecido al caso que respondiste esa vez. Ayudame

Comment: @LuisCazares ya lo edite, yo estoy que hago de un hospital y mi caso es que tengo varios diagnosticos para una persona, pero son N diagnosticos. Mi codigo lo apdate al tuyo

Comment: ¿Quieres que las columnas muestren todos los diagnósticos posibles o sólo la máxima cantidad por paciente?

Comment: @LuisCazares yo quisiera que se muestren todas las columnas de diagnosticos para cada paciente, son N diagnosticos :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es un detalle rápido de como se puede hacer. Por lo general, es mejor hacer esto en el producto final.

```
--Establecemos las variables que vamos a utilizar.
DECLARE @SQL1 nvarchar(MAX) = '',
        @SQL2 nvarchar(MAX) = '',
        @SQL3 nvarchar(MAX) = '',
        @SQLFull nvarchar(MAX) = '',
        @Cuantos int;
```

Lo primero que hacemos es dividir la consulta en 3 partes. El **cabecero** que incluye el SELECT y todas las columnas fijas, la **parte dinámica** y el **final** que incluye el FROM y el resto de la consulta. Si te fijas, solo convertí la consulta en cadenas y dejé pendiente una parte para hacerla dinámica

```
SET @SQL1 = N'
WITH PacientesDiagnosticos AS(
    SELECT top 100
        p.IdPaciente      , 
       (p.ApellidoPaterno+'' ''+p.ApellidoMaterno+'' ''+p.PrimerNombre) as Nombres,
        p.NroDocumento         ,
        p.FechaNacimiento,
        d.Descripcion    AS Dignostico,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY p.IdPaciente ORDER BY a.IdAtencion, d.Descripcion) AS NumDiagnostico
    FROM Pacientes p
    JOIN Atenciones a ON p.IdPaciente = a.IdPaciente
    JOIN AtencionesDiagnosticos ad ON a.IdAtencion = ad.IdAtencion
    JOIN Diagnosticos d ON ad.IdDiagnostico = d.IdDiagnostico
)
SELECT IdPaciente
       ,Nombres
       ,NroDocumento
       ,FechaNacimiento'
       --MAX( CASE WHEN NumDiagnostico = 1 THEN Dignostico END) AS Dignostico1,
       --MAX( CASE WHEN NumDiagnostico = 2 THEN Dignostico END) AS Dignostico2,
       --MAX( CASE WHEN NumDiagnostico = 3 THEN Dignostico END) AS Dignostico3,
       --MAX( CASE WHEN NumDiagnostico = 4 THEN Dignostico END) AS Dignostico4,
       --MAX( CASE WHEN NumDiagnostico = 5 THEN Dignostico END) AS Dignostico5,
       --MAX( CASE WHEN NumDiagnostico = 6 THEN Dignostico END) AS Dignostico6
SET @SQL3 = N'
FROM PacientesDiagnosticos
GROUP BY IdPaciente, 
       Nombres, 
       NroDocumento,
       FechaNacimiento;';
```

Después, necesitamos ver como construir la parte dinámica. En este caso, son sólo números y podemos hacerlo de distintas formas. Primero cuento la cantidad máxima de elementos y luego uso una tabla de números (tally table) para evitar escribir un bucle al formar la cadena.

```
SELECT TOP 1
    @Cuantos = COUNT(*)
FROM Pacientes p
JOIN Atenciones a ON p.IdPaciente = a.IdPaciente
JOIN AtencionesDiagnosticos ad ON a.IdAtencion = ad.IdAtencion 
GROUP BY p.IdPaciente
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;

WITH 
E(n) AS(--10 filas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( --10x10 = 100 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( 100x100 = 10,000 filas posibles
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP(@Cuantos) --limitamos las filas para obtener las necesarias
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n --generamos los numeros
    FROM E4
)--armamos la cadena concatenando fila por fila
SELECT @SQL2 = @SQL2 + CHAR(10)  + CHAR(9) + REPLACE( N',MAX( CASE WHEN NumDiagnostico = <<n>> THEN Dignostico END) AS Dignostico<<n>>', '<<n>>', n)
FROM cteTally;

--Unimos las 4 partes
SET @SQLFull = @SQL1 + @SQL2 + @SQL3;

--Esto es para ayudarnos a debuggear
PRINT @SQLFull;

--Aquí se ejecuta la consulta. Recuerda usar parámetros en caso de ser necesario en vez de concatenar valores.
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLFull--, N'@Param1 int, @Param2 datetime', @Param1, @Param2, etc.
```

Comment: valla man! Eres un maestrazo! Gracias, me ayudo bastante!

Comment: Espero que lo entiendas y, de no ser así, preguntes lo que haga falta.

Comment: gracias por el apoyo :D ! Si un caso tengo alguna duda te estare preguntando en los dias siguientes, gracias por el apoyo. Otra vez :D