# Convertir filas a columnas. Varias filas

Tags: sql-server, tsql, pivot

Tengo esta tabla origen:

**update: añado columnas Id and IdGestion**

```
Id  IdGestion   PeticionId  Field       Value
48  17          16          Type        1
49  17          16          SubType     1
50  17          16          Units       1
51  18          16          Type        1
52  18          16          SubType     2
53  18          16          Units       2
54  19          16          Type        3
55  19          16          SubType     6
56  19          16          Units       1
```

El objetivo es obtener unos datos así, de 9 filas a 3 filas y sus 4 columnas:

```
RequestId            Type    SubType         Units
16          1       1       1
16          1       2       2
16          3       6           1
```

Intento hacer PIVOT, pero pide función de agregado, y además, cómo coger grupos de 3 en 3 filas

```
select g.PeticionId,  Tipo,SubTipo,Unidades from [GestionSaliente] g
inner join (
SELECT PeticionId,  Tipo,SubTipo,Unidades
FROM
    (select  gs.PeticionId, Campo, Valor 
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY gs.IdGestion ORDER BY gsd.Id) as rn
       FROM [GestionSaliente]  gs
        inner join [GestionSalienteDato] gsd
        on gs.Id = gsd.GestionSalienteId --where  PeticionId = 16 
        
    ) AS source
    PIVOT
    (
     MIN(Valor)
     FOR Campo IN (Tipo,SubTipo,Unidades)
    ) as pvt

) a
on a.PeticionId = g.PeticionId
```

Alguna alternativa?

Comment: ¿Cómo decides cuales filas van juntas?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo pasar datos de filas a columnas - SQL Server?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/254644/c%c3%b3mo-pasar-datos-de-filas-a-columnas-sql-server)

Comment: @LuisCazares Dígamos cada 3 filas es un grupo ( Type    SubType         Units). DE las 9 filas, se convertirían a 3 filas y con las columnas  Type    SubType         Units más el Id. PIVOT requiere una función de agregado :'(

Comment: Entiendo que así lo ves, pero dentro de una tabla no hay ningún orden establecido. Por lo que no se puede saber cuales combinaciones de tipo, subtipo y unidades son las correctas.

Comment: @LuisCazares update: añado columnas Id and IdGestion. Pensaba que con ROW_NUMBER podría solucionarse, no creo que sea necesario, tengo Id para identificar la fila y IdGestion para el "grupo". En foro: _"you don't need a rownumber. You just select RequestId, GroupId, Field, Value, and then pivot these on the contents of the Field column. You'll get 3 rows, with 5 columns: RequestId, GroupId, Type, Subtype, Units. It won't collapse to 1 row like before, because the GroupId is now present to distinguish."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A menos que haya una buena razón para asegurarse en el SQL que solo sean 3 registros por grupo, yo solamente me quedaría con el hecho de que *los datos son así* (según se observa en el ejemplo).

Para hacer un pivot siempre hay que usar una función de agregación, dado que nosotros sabemos que hay un registro de cada tipo, podemos usar indistintamente `min()` o `max()` para llenar ese requisito, con lo que esta consulta debiera devolver lo que buscas:

```sql
select *
  from (select idGestion, PeticionID, Field, Value
          from GestionSaliente
       ) t
 pivot (min(Value)
        for Field in (Type, SubType, Units)
       ) as pt;
```

En mis pruebas obtengo:`

```
idGestion   PeticionID  Type        SubType     Units
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
17          16          1           1           1
18          16          1           2           2
19          16          3           6           1

(3 rows affected)
```

[fiddle de ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Vlti27oR)

Como puedes ver, tienes que incluir el campo `idGestion` que es el que los *agrupa*.

Si no te interesa en el resultado final, te puedes deshacer de él, por ejemplo:

```sql
select PeticionID, Type, SubType, Units
  from (select idGestion, PeticionID, Field, Value
          from GestionSaliente
       ) t
 pivot (min(Value)
        for Field in (Type, SubType, Units)
       ) as pt;
```

[fiddle del segundo ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/DyffxK7B)

Te devolvería:

```
PeticionId  Type        SubType     Units
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
16          1           1           1
16          1           2           2
16          3           6           1

(3 rows affected)
```

**Edición**:

Mi ejemplo original era más complicado de lo que debía ser, agradezco a [@LuisCazares](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/117337/luis-cazares) hacermelo ver y aportar el fiddle del ejemplo que ahora aparece en la respuesta.

Mi código original, dónde evidentemente el CTE estaba de más, era:

```sql
with
x as (
select *
  from (select idGestion, PeticionID, Field, Value
          from GestionSaliente
       ) t
 pivot (min(Value)
        for Field in (Type, SubType, Units)
       ) as pt
)
select PeticionId, Type, SubType, Units
  from X;
```

[fiddle original del segundo ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/P9PKpA1n)

Comment: Podrías simplemente especificar las columnas sin necesidad de usar el CTE.

Comment: En la segunda consulta, si no especifico todas las columnas en el pivot, va a devolver solo 1 fila, a ese nivel se hace necesario incluir la columna `idGestion`, que luego no aparece en el resultado final, por eso he utilizado un CTE.

Comment: Me refiero a cambiar el asterisco por las columnas. Haciendo el cambio ahí, no se necesita el código extra. Al final, no afecta realmente, pero el código queda más sencillo.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/DyffxK7B